# How to get the table structure in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, schema

my task is to get the table structure in SQL Server (that means what are all the columns and their data type and constraints)

Comment: Just run `sp_help tablename`?

Comment: thank you James, your query is working for me.

Answer (score 2):

This will list all columns, the schema and table they belong to, their datatype, max length, precision and scale (for numerical types) - what more are you looking for??

```
SELECT
    SchemaName = sch.name,
    TableName = t.Name,
    ColumnName = c.Name,
    TypeName = ty.Name,
    MaxLength = c.max_length,
    Precision = c.precision,
    Scale = c.scale
FROM 
    sys.columns c
INNER JOIN 
    sys.tables t ON t.object_id = c.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.schemas sch ON sch.schema_id = t.schema_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.types ty ON c.user_type_id = ty.user_type_id
```

Answer (score 1):

**sp_help** can be used to get all the details about a table. 
You can do something like this -

**Execute sp_help yourtableName**

Comment: its also working, may i know the difference between 'exec sp_help '[M3FDBTST].[MVXJDTA].[CMNCMP]';' and  'sp_help tablename?';